# abstract methods problems when extending FOSUB UserManager

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm trying to extends FOSUB UserManger according to their [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/user_manager.html)
I created a service (app/config/services.yml):

```
services:
my_custom_user_manager:
    class: UserBundle\Repository\CustomUserManager
    arguments: []
```

Modified the config (app/config/config.yml):

```
fos_user:
service:
    user_manager: my_custom_user_manager
```

And created the class :

```
    <?php

namespace UserBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManager;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface;

class CustomUserManager extends UserManager implements UserManagerInterface
{

    public function loadUserByUsername($username)
    {

        return $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->where('u.username = :username OR u.email = :email')
            ->setParameter('username', $username)
            ->setParameter('email', $username)
            ->join('u.roleues','r')
            ->addSelect('r')
            ->join('r.etablissement','e')
            ->addSelect('e')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getOneOrNullResult();

    }


}
```

But I get this error :

```
Error: Class UserBundle\Repository\CustomUserManager contains 5 abstract methods and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface::deleteUser, FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface::findUsers, FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface::getClass, ...)
```

But when I read the [Usermanager](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Model/UserManager.php) class and the UserManagerInterface, I can't see any absract method, when I read similar subjects, they extend this class without any problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An interface does not have abstract methods. It just declares methods you need to implement in your class.

Since the methods listed in your error message are not implemented by the `FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManager`, you have to implement them on your `UserBundle\Repository\CustomUserManager`.

Also, if you extend the `FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManager`, you don't have to implement the `FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface`, since the `FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManager` already implements it.

For a better understanding, I recommand you to read some documentation about inheritance in OOP. You can find some PHP doc about it: [Object Inheritance](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php), [Interfaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php) and [Abstract classes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php).

Comment: Ok thanks, I understand my mistake, I had to extend FOS\UserBundle\**Doctrine**\UserManager; and not FOS\UserBundle\**Model**\UserManager;